# HTML table display only two decimal points and format as a currency. (found Javascript function but don't know how to implement)

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, decimalformat

I am trying to have my html table only display 2 decimals points and have it format the last four columns of my tables as currency. I found this function online which is Javascript but I don't know how to implement it. Could someone help?

Here someone lays out the Javascript code: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/format-currency/

this is my code:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <table style="width:100%" class="table">

        <tr>
            <th> ID </th>
            <th> Username </th>
            <th> Stock </th>
            <th> Amount </th>
            <th> Current Price </th>
            <th> Total Value </th>
            <th> Current Cash </th>
            <th> Grand Total </th>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> {{ user_id }} </td>
                <td> {{ username }} </td>
                <td> {{ stocks }} </td>
                <td> {{ amount }} </td>
                <td> {{ price }} </td>
                <td> {{ (amount * price) }} </td>
                <td> {{ current_cash }} </td>
                <td> {{ grand_tot }} </td>

            </tr>


</table>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `amount.toFixed(2)` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, just use the same function, CurrencyFormatted, that he has mentioned, and use the following code:

```
<tr>
    <td> {{ user_id }} </td>
    <td> {{ username }} </td>
    <td> {{ stocks }} </td>
    <td> {{ amount }} </td>
    <td> {{ CurrencyFormatted(price) }} </td>
    <td> {{ CurrencyFormatted(amount * price) }} </td>
    <td> {{ CurrencyFormatted(current_cash) }} </td>
    <td> {{ CurrencyFormatted(grand_tot) }} </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pipe` in `HTML` to proper `currency format:| currency:"INR"`:

```
{{ Amount| currency:"INR"}}
```

Output:

```
 ₹100.00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>{{item.GradeAVG.toFixed(0)}}</td>
<td>{{item.TarazAVG.toFixed(2)}}</td>
```